# keep text inside div with firefox

Tags: firefox, text, overflow

Please open this fiddle with both firefox and Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattdevo/5bdDd/

as you may notice, text flows past div in firefox.

What is my mistake? (removing strong tags did not help...)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `display:-moz-box;`; if you really need it you should also add `-moz-box-orient: vertical;`

Answer (score 2):

Using a Firefox only display type leads to incompatibility, that's normal.

If you remove

```
display:-moz-box;
```

This works in FF as in Chrome.

Comment: ..Is there another way?  I am using the flex box model. it works when -webkit-box is added. Thanks for the input

Comment: Did you try with `display: box;` ? If I miss something, maybe you need to put in fiddle a more complete example so that we can see what are all the requirements ?

Comment: actually. I can work would your solution. I can still use box-flex without the moz box tag.. not sure why